# How do I render a partial containing a form_for for an edit function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a `div` in a parent view that renders a `show` partial. In this `show` partial, I have a button that should change the parent's partial to render the 'form' partial to edit the object, but I keep getting jammed up because it seems that the 'form' partial's `form_for` is missing the `@project` object.

How can I pass this object to the 'form' partial? Am I missing something else?

I am rather new to using AJAX. Happy to provide more information if you need.

The error I am getting in the server terminal is

```
ActionView::Template::Error (First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty):
```

**routes.rb**

```
    get 'switchProjectView', to: 'projects#switch_main_view'
    resources :projects
```

**projects_controller.rb**

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @project = Project.new
  end

  def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)
    if @project.save
      flash[:success] = "New Project Added"
      redirect_to @project 
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Project Not Added. Please Try Again"
    end

  end

  def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @projects = Project.all
  end

  def update 
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    if @project.update_attributes(project_params)
      redirect_to @project
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def edit

  end

  def switch_main_view
    respond_to do |format|               
      format.html
      format.js
    end    
  end     


  def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:main_contact_name, :id, :main_contact_phone, :main_contact_email, :project_name)
  end

end
```

**show.html.erb**

```
    <div class="body">
      <div class="center jumbotron heading-jumbo">
        <h1><%= @project.project_name %></h1>  
      </div>

      <div class="body-jumbo jumbotron" id='project-details'>
        <%= render "projects/show" %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**switch_main_view.js.erb**

```
    $('#project-details').html("<%= j render :partial => 'projects/form' %>");
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
  <%= form_for(@project) do |f| %>

      <%= f.label :project_name %>
      <%= f.text_field :project_name, class: 'form-control'%>

      <%= f.label :main_contact_name %>
      <%= f.text_field :main_contact_name, class: 'form-control'%>

      <%= f.label :main_contact_phone %>
      <%= f.text_field :main_contact_phone, class: 'form-control'%>

      <%= f.label :main_contact_email %>
      <%= f.text_field :main_contact_email, class: 'form-control'%>

      <%= f.submit 'Save Project', class: 'btn btn-primary'%>

  <% end %>
```

**_show.html.erb**

```
<div class='text-center center'>
    <h3><strong>Project Information</strong></h2>  
</div>
<h2>Start Date: Launch Date:</h1>
<span class='pull-right jumbo-btn-span'><%= link_to "Edit Project Information", switchProjectView_path(@project), remote: true, class:'btn btn-primary jumbo-btn' %></span>
<h2>Primary Conact's Name:  <%= @project.main_contact_name %></h2>
<h2>Primary Conact's Phone: <%= @project.main_contact_phone %></h2>
<h2>Primary Conact's Email: <%= @project.main_contact_email %></h2>
```

Comment: Did you declare @project in the controller of the main view?

Comment: Yes, I have. The project/show partial on the parent show.html.erb is displaying the @project data correctly

Comment: The problem is that ruby variables render with the page, and the browser isn't recalling it when you're adding the partial. If it's already declared, have you thought about just hiding the div but loading it with the page, and then displaying it when needed, instead of adding the html later?

Comment: That makes sense and it's certainly an option. Is there any way to pass the variable to the partial via the js file and the link_to?

Comment: Through ajax you can. The server variables are declared, then the page is loaded. So by appending .html, you are skipping the first part and just appending html. Even though it seems reasonable that you could keep using them, since they are 'server variables' the browser can not just keep manipulating them. If you think about the error: @project.something = nil. The server isn't being pinged for that project record, to see what .something is.

Comment: Would you please post the complete code from your controller, like any filters?

Comment: Thank You! I hate to be so blunt but how would I do this via Ajax? Would I make another call in the _form partial ?

Comment: I just posted the full controller. I tried putting a known @project object in the edit method and it doesn't work in the partial

Comment: @got2jam Have a look at my answer. I have updated it.

Comment: I would really encourage you to load everything on the page on the inital view, and just hide the form, and display it when needed. But yes, switchProjectView_path(@project) could be an ajax call. Then, you would append the form, using the variables from the results. Looking below, @Arslan Ali has a great answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request "switchProjectView_path(@project)" only send object id to server, so you need to load the object to present it in view for response.
1. First the route should look like this so that, the url could contain object id:
`get 'switchProjectView/:id', to: 'projects#switch_main_view', as:"switchProjectView"`
2. You have to load the object in controller:

`def switch_main_view
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end 
end`

Comment: This wound up doing the trick. I was able to render find and render the @project object with the params / controller method. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Well, with each request, you need to re-initialize the variable in your controller method. In your case, you need to do the following:

```
def switch_main_view
  @project = Project.new
  respond_to do |format|               
    format.html
    format.js
  end    
end
```

Doing so will enable you to get rid of the error: **First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty**, but that won't enable you to do what you are actually trying to do.

When you use `link_to`, by default it goes for an HTML request as you can see in Rails logs, something like following will appear:

```
Processing by ProjectsController#switch_main_view as HTML
```

In order to get the JS response, you need to tell `link_to` that you are up for a JS response, not for an HTML response, and you can do by passing `format: :js` in `link_to` like:

```
<%= link_to "Edit Project Information", switchProjectView_path(@project, format: :js), remote: true, class:'btn btn-primary jumbo-btn' %></span>
```

`remote: true` will be there to make sure that you aren't reloading the contents of the page, rather you are trying to fetch something from the server in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the variable when calling the partial:

```
$('#project-details').html("<%= j render :partial => 'projects/form', locals: {project: @project} %>");
```

Comment: still nothing :-(

FWIW, the partial renders when there is no variable in it.